# How to process a Fahrenheit temperature from EditText and print its corresponding Celsius temperature?

Tags: android, eclipse, textview

I am confused with the concept of creating a Listener in Android. The purpose of my program is simple: to convert between units (such as Fahrenheit to Celsius, Celsius to Fahrenheit, etc.). How do I get the text in the EditText object and then how do I print it out? I am getting an error everytime I run (Unfortunately, Converter.exe has stopped.) Here is my code so far. Please advise.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ConverterActivity extends Activity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.temp_Button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.body);
        }
    });  

    Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OK_Button);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            EditText et = (EditText) getText(0);
            final int num = Integer.parseInt(et.toString());
            double answer = (num - 32) * 5/9;
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            tv.setText(Double.toString(answer));
        }
    });

}
}
```

I have two layout (.xml) files as well (I am not sure if this is proper programming style).

main simply displays the buttons that can be clicked. Then, I have the second .xml file come up after the button is clicked.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/temp_Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/F" />
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/C" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/I" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Cm" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

body.xml (the second one)-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Enter temperature:" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:digits="1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel_Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/OK_Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Just to reiterate, my problem occurs with this segment of code:

```
 Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OK_Button);
   ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
   {
       public void onClick(View v)
        {
            EditText et = (EditText) getText(0);
            final int num = Integer.parseInt(et.toString());
            double answer = (num - 32) * 5/9;
           TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
           tv.setText(Double.toString(answer));
        }
   });
```

The intent is to get the number from the EditText object that the user inputs, convert it, and print it back out, but I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, or if this is even in the right place.

**UPDATE: Here is log.

```
02-06 19:53:36.148: D/AndroidRuntime(529): Shutting down VM
02-06 19:53:36.158: W/dalvikvm(529): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sapra.converter/com.sapra.converter.ConverterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at com.sapra.converter.ConverterActivity.onCreate(ConverterActivity.java:29)
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-06 19:53:36.168: E/AndroidRuntime(529):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: What error? And `getText(0)` isn't right. Use `getText().toString()`.

Comment: aneal, my question is ASKING if my code is right? I corrected my mistake that you mentioned (thank you for that). Do you see anything specifically wrong?

Comment: What happens when you click your button? Do you have a log? Those are useful things to mention and upload.

Comment: What is line 29 in ConverterActivity?

Comment: Do you mean the 'public void onClick(View v)'? So, when the user types a number and clicks the OK button, this method is supposed to take the number, convert it to Celsius form, and then display it back to the user. (If that was the wrong line, could you just type it so I know what you mean?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward, I think you can figure it out from here.

```
// This is the TextView you set in your layout. It will display the temperature.
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    // This sets up the EditText so you can capture the input and return the temperature.
    final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                // Perform action on key press
                float f = Float.parseFloat(edittext.getText().toString());
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(convertCelciusToFahrenheit(f)));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}

// Converts to celcius
private float convertFahrenheitToCelcius(float fahrenheit) {
    return ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9);
}

// Converts to fahrenheit
private float convertCelciusToFahrenheit(float celsius) {
    return ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it. I will work from here and see if I can understand more about the syntax of this program. (and perhaps expand on it too :))

Answer (score 0):

Just as an example. I wrote this sample temp converter awhile ago. Perhaps somebody might find it useful.

---

```
public class TempTest extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);           
        ll.setOrientation(1);
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("get temperature");
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view) {
                   getCelciusOrFarenheit();
            }
        });
        ll.addView(b);
        setContentView(ll);
    }

    public AlertDialog getCelciusOrFarenheit(){
    AlertDialog.Builder cof = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    cof.setTitle("Select Temperature Conversion");
    String[] types = {"To Celcius", "To Farenheit"};
    cof.setItems(types, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            switch(which){
            case 0:
                createTempDialog(true).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                createTempDialog(false).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    return cof.show();
    }
    public AlertDialog createTempDialog(final boolean cf){
       final EditText et = new EditText(this);
       et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
       final Formatter f = new Formatter();
       return new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(et).setTitle(cf?"Enter Farenheit temperature":"Enter Celcius temperature").setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
               double answer = 0;
               if (cf) {
                   answer = (Double.parseDouble(et.getText().length() > 1 ? et.getText().toString() : "0") - 32) * 5 / 9;
               } else {
                   answer = Double.parseDouble(et.getText().length() > 1 ? et.getText().toString() : "0")*9/5 + 32;
               }
               new AlertDialog.Builder(TempTest.this).setMessage(f.format("%.2f", answer).toString()).setTitle(cf?"Celcius":"Farenheit")
                       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                               dialogInterface.dismiss();
                           }
                       })
                       .create().show();
           }
       }).create();
    }

}
```

Comment: wow, this looks very confusing. Also, I tried running this on my computer and it gave me a compiler error for f.format.

Comment: I just ran it without any problems mate. I wouldnt post it if I wasnt a working sample. You have probably imported a wrong Formatter.

Comment: yeah its probably my fault. Sorry. But can you help me?